# User 'user1'@'localhost' can perform actions that are only permitted for 'user1'@'%'

Tags: mysql

Im MySQL, `'user1'@'localhost'` and `'user1'@'%'` are considered two different users, and we can set two different passwords for them.

However, say if you grant some privileges to `'user1'@'%'`, you will not see those privileges for `'user1'@'localhost'` using `SHOW GRANTS` or from the tables in `mysql` database, but `'user1'@'localhost'` can still perform those actions.

So how does MySQL determine if the current user has sufficient privilege to perform an action? The behavior seems very unintuitive to me.

Let's see the example. First, we create users and a database. Notice that we are actually using two different passwords.

```sql
mysql> CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwlocalhost';
mysql> CREATE USER 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwanywhere';
mysql> CREATE DATABASE db1;
mysql> CREATE TABLE db1.tb1 (a int primary key);
mysql> INSERT INTO db1.tb1 VALUES (1);
mysql> GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'user1'@'%';
```

Now log in. We know we are logged in as `'user1'@'localhost'` because we use `pwlocalhost` as password and we can also check that once we logged in:

```bash
$mysql -u user1 --password=pwlocalhost
```

```sql
mysql> SELECT USER();
+-----------------+
| USER()          |
+-----------------+
| user1@localhost |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

This user has no privileges on `db1` but can still perform actions:

```sql
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+-------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user1@localhost                |
+-------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `user1`@`localhost` |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM db1.tb1;
+---+
| a |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: The `%` wildcard character in the host part of the account name means “any host” but does not include `localhost`. The privileges for `‘user1’@‘localhost’` and `‘user1’@‘%’` are indeed considered separately.

Comment: When you log in as `‘user1’@‘localhost’`, MySQL will check for privileges for `‘user1’@‘localhost’`. If no such user exists, it will then check for `‘user1’@‘%’`. This is why you can still perform actions on db1 even though `‘user1’@‘localhost’` does not explicitly have those privileges

Comment: @esQmo_, Thanks for your quick comment! That's what I suspect about how MySQL is checking privileges. I asked this because it's actually confusing---they are two users, but one user can use the other user's privileges. I guess this is also potentially exploitable: if I do not know the password for `'user1'@'%'`, but I managed to create `'user1'@'localhost'`, I will be able to do whatever `'user1'@'%'` can do.

Comment: You’re right that this behavior can potentially be exploited if not properly managed. It’s important to understand that MySQL’s user privilege resolution is based on the ‘most specific match’ principle. This means that MySQL will always try to match the most specific host definition.

Comment: In your example, if `‘user1’@‘localhost’` exists, MySQL will not fall back to `‘user1’@‘%’`. However, if `‘user1’@‘localhost’` does not exist, MySQL will then try to match `‘user1’@‘%’`. This is why it’s possible for `‘user1’@‘localhost’` to use the privileges of `‘user1’@‘%’` if `‘user1’@‘localhost’` does not have explicit privileges defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in, MySQL sorts all the users in the `mysql.user` table by "most specific host", then takes the first one that matches your username. That account is what you'll see in `SELECT CURRENT_USER()` or `SHOW GRANTS`

If you create only `'username'@'%'`, then that's the user which will be used if you log in as 'username', no matter where you come from - localhost via TCP, localhost via Unix socket file, or some other machine via TCP.

If you create both `'username'@'%'` and also `'username'@'localhost'`, then the 'localhost' is more specific, so connections coming from localhost will authenticate as that user instead of the @'%' account. This behavior is what makes some people erroneously believe that '%' does not include localhost. It does; it's just that a 'localhost' entry in mysql.user will supercede a '%' entry of the same name.

Privileges stored in the `mysql.user` table are global - GRANT <whatever> ON ***.*** TO.... Every created user gets an entry in `mysql.user`, and if you don't grant them any global privileges, then `SHOW GRANTS` will show only the `USAGE` privilege, meaning they can log in and nothing else.

You can also grant privileges at the database level - GRANT <whatever> ON **someDBName**.* TO... - and these get stored in the `mysql.db` table instead. Likewise there's a table for table-level privileges and one for column-level privileges.

When you run a query, MySQL first checks the `mysql.user` table to see if you have the necessary global privileges. The row it will find there will match the one it used to log you in. So the global privileges for the @'%' user are completely separate from the @localhost user (assuming both exist).

If you do not have the global privilege needed for the query, then it checks the `mysql.db` table for a database level privilege. Again, it sorts the entries by "most specific host", and then takes the first row that matches your user name and the database involved in the query. That means that if you have done only `GRANT ALL ON someDBName.* TO 'username'@'%'`, then that row will match anybody called 'username' from any host, including localhost. Thus the @localhost user gets the @'%' database-level privileges.

The fact that those privileges don't appear in the SHOW GRANTS statement was reported in 2010 as [bug 53645](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53645).

However, if you then add a database-level privilege with a more specific host name, such as `GRANT SELECT ON someDBName.* TO 'username'@'localhost'`, then this more specific entry will be sorted higher and get picked first. The multiple matching rows do not combine; @localhost user will no longer have the 'ALL' privilege that was granted to the @'%' user. In that case, if the database-level privilege isn't enough, it will go on to check the table-level and then the column-level, using the same "most specific host" sorting method.

This behavior is covered in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/request-access.html).